# converting tex commands (latex) to mathml

Tags: javascript, mathjax

I noticed that while clicking on math equation, we are given choices to view the source of the Tex Commands as well as view the mathml. Is there a way that I can compile Tex Commands wrapped in between $$ into mathml code directly using JavaScript library?

[image]

Comment: Isn't that what this library "MathJax" does? (Although probably MJ converts its input in an abstract model first, and then can generate all of the different outputs.)

Comment: @Jongware I think so, but it uses different tags than mathml. I get this from source of mathjax
`<span class="MathJax" id="MathJax-Element-304-Frame" role="textbox" aria-readonly="true"><nobr><span class="math" id="MathJax-Span-2807" style="width: 10.929em; dy ...`

Answer (score 1):

The [MathJax-node](http://github.com/mathjax/MathJax-node) project implements a command-line API to MathJax that allows you to use MathJax to process single equations or pages containing math.  You can use it to convert an HTML page containing TeX code to one containing MathML instead using the `page2mml` command in the `bin` directory of the project.